# Applying a theme to a menu item?

Tags: android

Sorry if this question sounds stupid, but I am new to android and need help. I have two menu items

```
  <item android:id="@+id/submenu11" android:title="Newest" android:icon="@android:drawable/radiobutton_off_background"  />
  <item android:id="@+id/submenu12" android:title="Oldest" android:icon="@android:drawable/radiobutton_off_background"/>
```

They use the radio button icon, but when I launch the app its just a grey circle- unlike what it is supposed to look like. How do I add a theme, or color these icons so that they are not just grey circles and look more like radio buttons? Thanks in advance, would really help

Answer (score 0):

Of question, you just used a radio_off icon, if you want to set an radio button as menu, you should create a custom button on it,like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_navigate_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```

You can use "actionViewClass" to set a custom view, of you want, there can write android.widget.RadioButton

Comment: Im using a navigation view which doesnt support that im pretty sure